# How can backpropagation through convolutional neural networks be vectorized?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have got a good grasp of backpropagation algorithm for fully connected neural networks and I can derive the vectorized implementation for it but after getting into convulutional networks, I think due to my not-so-strong linear algebra background, I have a lot of trouble trying to come up with a fully vectorized implementation for backpropagation.

The network architecture is as follows :-

```
Input->conv->relu->pool->fully_connected_network
```

I have used only one convolutional Layer for simplifaication

How can the vectorized implementation of this network be derived ?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Aaron Well I know the formula for convolution so I can calculate element-wise derivative but I want to vectorize it.

Comment: Start with one-dimensional case with only 1 variable. Derive derivatives. Extend to slightly harder case, again, derive derivatives, combine them into vector form (should be easy once correct derivatives are computed); alternatively you can lookup a the answer in the book. Then move to the most general case which is for images.

Comment: @Gnattuha I have read an article and understood most of the derivation but I'm stuck . [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011981/generalization-of-gradient-calculation-for-multi-channel-convolutions) are more details about my problem. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert all kernels to columns and get a kernels matrix
2. Split your input (image) on slices for convolution then convert to columns and get an input matrix. You can append other inputs (images) to form a mini-batch
3. multiply transposed input matrix on kernels matrix. In the result matrix each column is one feature map.

Look [here](http://lxu.me/mypapers/vcnn_aaai15.pdf) for more details